# c++ over linux gcc inheritence

Tags: c++, linux, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit a Class called TCPSocket with class user. In spite of the fact that I'm using ifndef I get the message:
‘User::User(int, sockaddr_in, sockaddr_in)’ previously defined here

This is from my header file:

```
#ifndef USER_H_
#define USER_H_

#include <string.h>
#include "TCPSocket.h"


class User : TCPSocket {
string _U_Name;
string _in_session;
string _in_room;

public:
User(int connected_sock,struct sockaddr_in server_addr, struct sockaddr_in peer_addr)
:TCPSocket(connected_sock,server_addr, peer_addr);
    virtual ~User();
};

#endif /* USER_H_ */
```

Comment: Maybe your partially implemented constructor is confusing the compiler. You need to give it a body, since you already have a constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor is partially implemented in the header file:

```
User(int connected_sock, sockaddr_in server_addr, sockaddr_in peer_addr)
: TCPSocket(connected_sock,server_addr, peer_addr);
```

Either remove the initialization list, if you have implemented the constructor in the `.cpp` file:

```
User(int connected_sock, sockaddr_in server_addr, sockaddr_in peer_addr);
```

or complete the implementation by adding a body, and make sure it is **not** defined in the `.cpp`:

```
User(int connected_sock, sockaddr_in server_addr, sockaddr_in peer_addr) 
: TCPSocket(connected_sock,server_addr, peer_addr)
{
   ....
}
```

Note that in C++ you don't have to type `struct` all over the place. Also note that inheritance for a `class` is `private` by default, so you are inheriting privately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the base class initaliser from your header file and move it to your implementation, i.e. remove the TCPSocket(...)